# Open ViewController from different class

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to open a ViewController from a different class. So I could simply call it to open a view wherever I need it.

So I have this setup in the class that holds the code:

---

```
+ (void)openCalcView: (NSString *)nameOfView {

UIViewController *controller;

if ([nameOfView isEqualToString:@"Tax"]) {

    controller = [[TAXViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TAXViewController" bundle:nil];


}else if ([nameOfView isEqualToString:@"Rent"]){

    controller = [[RENTViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RENTViewController" bundle:nil];

}

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
[controller release];

}
```

---

But `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];` gives me a warning:

`Class method '+presentViewController:animated:completion:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

I can call simple things like `NSLog` through this, from any class. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to see if `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]` works?

Comment: @ScottBossak *self* does not exist in a class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because openCalcView is a Class method, there is no UIViewController instance (i.e. no [self presentViewController:] method).

You'll need to also pass a UIViewController to this class method, something like this:

```
+ (void)openCalcView: (NSString *)nameOfView fromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller { 

    UIViewController *newController; 

    if ([nameOfView isEqualToString:@"Tax"]) { 

        newController= [[TAXViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TAXViewController" bundle:nil]; 


    }else if ([nameOfView isEqualToString:@"Rent"]){ 

        newController= [[RENTViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RENTViewController" bundle:nil]; 

    } 

    newController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; 
    [controller presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
    [newController release]; 

}
```

the controller parameter represents the UIViewController that is opening the new view controller

Comment: actually, there is self in a class method. self points to the class

Comment: And how would I call this from another view?

Comment: you're calling it from another UIViewController, [youCalcViewClass openCalcView:@"Tax" fromViewController:self]